# Undefined method `new' Netzke Starting Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, netzke

I followed the [starting tutorial for Netzke](http://writelesscode.com/blog/2012/10/20/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/), but when the page would show me the grid, I have an error :

NoMethodError in Welcome#index

undefined method `new' for Tasks:Module

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= netzke :tasks, height: 400 %>

I have exactly the same code given in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run a `bundle install` before starting the app? It sounds like not all of the methods from Netzke were added to your application bundle. Also, don't forget to run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Oh thanks ! I think I had the problem because I ran "bundle install" and "rake db:migrate" while the server was running. So I shutdowned the server and ran them again.

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

add you netzke in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
netzke
root to: 'users#index'
end
```